# HTML Button Design with CSS?

Tags: html, css, button

my problem is the following:

This is a part of my HTML-Code:

```
<form method='GET' name='auftragaufgeben' action='AuftragAufgeben'>
    <input  type='submit' name='auftragaufgeben2' value='Auftrag aufgeben'>
    <input type='hidden' name='logged' value='logged'>
</form>
```

No i want a design for the button with the help of css. This is the code:

```
a.auftragaufgeben {
display: block;
background-image: url(AuftragAufgeben.png);
width: 467px;
height: 104px;
}

a.auftragaufgeben:hover {
background-image: url(AuftragAufgeben_Hover.png);
}
```

I found that the declaration of the class in the button tag should work, for example this:

```
<form method='GET' name='auftragaufgeben' action='AuftragAufgeben'>
<input  class="auftragaufgeben" type='submit' name='auftragaufgeben2' value='Auftrag aufgeben'>
    <input type='hidden' name='logged' value='logged'>
</form>
```

But this doesn't change anything.
How can change the layout of the button to the picture i declared in the CSS part?
Or is there another way to start the form when i click the picture?

Kind regards

Comment: Have you tried <button>?

Comment: No, i tried input type = "button".

How do i have to do that with <button>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your css, the code **a.auftragaufgeben** and **a.auftragaufgeben:hover** are for styling a link element, not the button.

try

```
.auftragaufgeben {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(AuftragAufgeben.png);
    width: 467px;
    height: 104px;
}

.auftragaufgeben:hover {
    background-image: url(AuftragAufgeben_Hover.png);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your final html code should look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .auftragaufgeben {
                display: block;
                background-image: url(AuftragAufgeben.png);
                width: 467px;
                height: 104px;
            }
            .auftragaufgeben:hover {
                background-image: url(AuftragAufgeben_Hover.png);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='GET' name='auftragaufgeben' action='AuftragAufgeben'>
            <input  class="auftragaufgeben" type='submit' name='auftragaufgeben2' value='Auftrag aufgeben'>
            <input type='hidden' name='logged' value='logged'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this again the declaration of the class after changing the CSS to your code again. Still no change :(

Edit: Another information: Im doing this in the HTML-output in a Java Servlet! Maybe there is a problem?

Comment: This is working in the HTML Code of a .html!
I will try that in the servlet!